# Uploading image with axios (react) and PHP

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios

I get this message on console when I do a request using Axios to a PHP file

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://cp.com.br/cpnr-upload/' from 
origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The thing is, the target file already has on top:
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

The request code in React:

```
handleUploadChange = (e) => {
let files = e.target.files;
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
reader.onload = (e) => {
  const url1 = "http://local.url/image-upload/";
  var data1 = new FormData();
  data1.set('action','upload');
  data1.set('file', e.target.result);
  return axios({
    method : "POST",
    url : url1,
    data : data1
  }).then(response => {
    console.warn("result", response);
  });
}
return;
```

the HTML code inside render function:

```
<input
      onChange = {this.handleUploadChange}
      className={classes.uploadInput}
      accept="image/*"
      id="outlined-button-file"
      multiple
      type="file"
/>
```

Comment: If you have chrome can you make the request again and have the network tab of browser tools open and check the actual request, look to see what the headers are on your request going out. Then let me know and I'll help you fix it.

Comment: this error message shows sometimes when you don't use https

Answer (score 0):

If you use Laravel, try to use this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors. If you are plain PHP, with Chrome browser (I guess you are), use this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi.
This is the CORS problem when you use React as frontend and PHP as backend.

PS: remember if you are localhost, use url as http://127.0.0.1 not http://localhost